# How can I generate a coverage.xml for Jenkins without using Maven/Ant from the Linux command line?

Tags: java, xml, linux, jenkins, code-coverage

## Hello!

### Problem description

I am fairly new to Linux, Jenkins and automated testing.
I wonder how I can generate a **coverage.xml** from the Linux command line or the Jenkins environment after running my code (see below)?

In Jenkins I want to show my code coverage by using Cobertura or Jacoco.
I use shell scripts *(bash)* to clean (removing the .class files), compile and run the tests from Jenkins (or the command line).

I have a very simple program in ***java*** that uses a set of very simple unit tests and one performance test (**testNG**).

#### Extra

I would like to find a way to generate this **coverage.xml** without the use of Maven or Ant if possible. As I do not know how to generate it even in my IDE I am gratefull for any explanatory answer in how to get a **coverage.xml**.

If it is not possible, how could I write my **pom.xml** for Maven to get this to work?

### Code: Program

The program is an automated, simple version of the ***FizzBuzz*** math game, where each player takes turns to count up, replacing each number that is evenly denomainated by a said denominator by another word (ex. "Fizz" but in this example "Cowabunga").

#### main.java

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StartGame game = new StartGame();
        game.start();
    }
}
```

#### StartGame.java

```
public class StartGame {
    public static void start() {
        GameRules gr = new GameRules(3,5);
        gr.startGame();
    }
}
```

#### GameRules.java

```
public class GameRules {
    private int currentNumber;
    private int currentPlayer;
    private int playUntilThisNumber;
    private int dividerToSkip;
    private List<Player> playerlist;


    public GameRules(int numberOfPlayers, int divider){
        playerlist = new ArrayList<Player>();
        currentNumber=1;
        currentPlayer=3;
        playUntilThisNumber = 100;
        dividerToSkip = divider;
        fillPlayerList(numberOfPlayers);
    }

    public int getCurrentNumber() {
        return currentNumber;
    }

    public void increaseCurrentNumber() {
        this.currentNumber++;
    } 

    private void fillPlayerList(int numberOfPlayers){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfPlayers ; i++){
            Player p = new Player(this, i+1,dividerToSkip);
            playerlist.add(p);
        }
    }

    public void startGame(){
        while(currentNumber<=playUntilThisNumber){
            System.out.println(playerlist.get(currentPlayer++%playerlist.size()).play());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Player.java

```
public class Player {
    private GameRules rules;
    private int dividerToSkip;
    private int playerNumber;


    public Player(GameRules r, int playerNr, int divider){
        rules = r;
        dividerToSkip = divider;
        playerNumber = playerNr;
    }

    public String play() {
        String s;
        if(rules.getCurrentNumber()%dividerToSkip==0){
            s = "Player " + playerNumber + ": Cowabunga";
        }
        else {
            s = "Player " + playerNumber + ": " +rules.getCurrentNumber();
        }
        rules.increaseCurrentNumber();
        return s;
    }
}
```

### Code: Tests

#### GameRuleTest.java

```
public class GameRulesTest {
        private int nrOfPLayers;
        private int divider;
        private GameRules gr;

        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp(){
            nrOfPLayers = 35;
            divider = 13;
            gr = new GameRules(nrOfPLayers,divider);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCurrentNumber(){
            assert (gr.getCurrentNumber()>0);
        }

        @Test
        public void testIncreaseCurrentNumber() {
            int cn = gr.getCurrentNumber();
            gr.increaseCurrentNumber();
            assert(gr.getCurrentNumber()==cn+1);
        } 
    }
```

#### PlayerTest.java

```
public class PlayerTest {
    private int nrOfPLayers;
    private int divider;
    private GameRules gr;
    private Player player;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        nrOfPLayers = 35;
        divider = 13;
        gr = new GameRules(nrOfPLayers,divider);
        player = new Player(gr,100,divider);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReturnString() {
        String res = player.play();

        assert "Player 100: 1".equals(res) : "Expected correct return string, got " + res;

        assertEquals("Player 100: 1", res);
    }
}
```

#### PerformanceTest.java

```
public class PerformanceTest {
    private StartGame game;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        game = new StartGame();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecutionTime(){
        long startTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        game.start();
        long finnishTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        System.out.println(startTime);
        System.out.println(finnishTime);
        assert (finnishTime-startTime<0.0000005);
    }
}
```

### Code: Scripts

#### clean.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.class' | xargs rm
```

#### compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
javac src/MindRoad/*.java
javac -cp src/:testng-6.8/testng-6.8.jar test/*.java
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp testng-6.8/testng-6.8.jar:test:src org.testng.TestNG -verbose 2 test/test.xml
```

#### test.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > 
<suite name="MindGameSuite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="MindGame"   >
    <classes>
      <class name="PlayerTest" />
      <class name="GameRulesTest" />
      <class name="PerformanceTest" />
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Thank you in advance for all your help!
Sincerely, RKrogh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the Cobertura coverage report, you are at luck - Cobertura allows you to run the tool from command line.

```
#Create the meta file (after javac)
cobertura-instrument.bat [--basedir dir] [--datafile file] [--auxClasspath classPath] [--destination dir] [--ignore regex] classes [...]

#Execution should include this extra jar in cp:
#Example
java -cp C:\cobertura\lib\cobertura.jar;C:\MyProject\build\instrumented;C:\MyProject\build\classes;C:\MyProject\build\test-classes -Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=C:\MyProject\build\cobertura.ser ASimpleTestCase

#Publish the report
cobertura-report.bat --format xml --datafile C:\MyProject\build\cobertura.ser --destination C:\MyProject\reports\coverage C:\MyProject\src
```

[This site](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) would help you.

Comment: Please note that the examples attached are Windows-specific. There are .sh counterparts of these scripts as well for Linux :)

Comment: Thank you a bunch!!
But there seems to be some error in Cobertura. An error message saying cobertura is missing a class shows up. Is there a work-around for these kind of errors? Do you know if they are known?

Comment: Did you download the entire stuff from GitHub?

Comment: Ah, sorry! there was a local misstake of calling another version of Cobertura instead of the intended. Much obliged!